# Delete files starting with particular word

Tags: android

In my application some temporary files are created,and its name starts with 'temp'. How to delete these files from sd card on exit .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can delete files from SDCARD as:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tempdirname");

 try {
    File[] filenamestemp = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i=0;i<filenamestemp.length;i++){
          if(filenamestemp[i].getAbsolutePath().toString().contains("temp"))
             filenamestemp[i].delete();     
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

and make sure you have added SDCARD access permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: got an error message    'The method contains(String) is undefined for the type File'